# Which email was the verification email sent to?

Tags: pokemon-go

I started my app today and it said that I needed to verify my email. But I don't know the email I chose. I logged on every email in but there was never a verify email. Is there a way to know your email on Pokemon Go?

Comment: Check the spam filter on all of those emails. Automated emails such as password recovery often end up there.

Comment: Guys. ***We don't magically know what email accounts you have, nor the one you typed in.***

Comment: Gmail needs no verification. If you logged in with a trainer account you can just visit their website. There you can see your account details. -> https://sso.pokemon.com/sso/login

Comment: Upvoted because even though I know the email that was sent, it didn't send to my outlook email

Answer (score 1):

If you created an account using the Pokemon Trainer club, you can verify which email address was used by logging into the site and clicking edit profile.

https://www.pokemon.com/us/pokemon-trainer-club/login

Comment: This only lasts 2 days after account creation. After 2 days, you won't be able to log in to click edit profile, because it will not let you log in -- it will ask if you want to resend the email, but it doesn't tell you which one.

Answer (score 0):

The email which you registered at pokemon or the google account you're using to play with.

You probably can find it on the official pokemon website for the account or just in your google account which most definetely has an email account attached to it.